# Converting Soap XML request to dictionary for Zeep

Tags: python, zeep

I'm having trouble converting this XML to relevant python dictionary soap request for passing into Zeep.Client.service.  The XML below comes from:

https://psix.uscg.mil/XML/PSIXData.asmx?op=getVesselSummaryXMLString

```
    POST /XML/PSIXData.asmx HTTP/1.1
    Host: psix.uscg.mil
    Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: length

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body>
        <getVesselSummaryXMLString xmlns="http://cgmix.uscg.mil">
          <VesselID>string</VesselID>
          <VesselName>string</VesselName>
          <CallSign>string</CallSign>
          <VIN>string</VIN>
          <HIN>string</HIN>
          <Flag>string</Flag>
          <Service>string</Service>
          <BuildYear>string</BuildYear>
        </getVesselSummaryXMLString>
      </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>
```

Ultimately I want to send a request to the soap server with the code below using a python dictionary as the "request_data" rather than the XML above, I'm just not sure which dictionary would be needed.

```
url = 'https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx?WSDL'
wsdl = url
client = zeep.Client(wsdl)
r = client.service.getVesselSummaryXMLString(request_data)
```

Comment: Not clear what exactly you want to achieve. You want to post this request to soap server? Or you want to process this as response? You don't have access to wsdl file?

Comment: I edited my original post so that it's more clear what I'm looking to achieve.  Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks. now your request is clear. I posted my answer. if you are satisfied with the answer then please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can inspect the wsdl methods by using this:

```
python -mzeep https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx?WSDL
```

from above, we can see that the `getVesselSummaryXMLString` method takes only string arguments:

```
getVesselSummaryXMLString(VesselID: xsd:string, VesselName: xsd:string, CallSign: xsd:string, VIN: xsd:string, HIN: xsd:string, Flag: xsd:string, Service: xsd:string, BuildYear: xsd:string) -> getVesselSummaryXMLStringResult: xsd:string
```

So you can call it simply as passing string arguments just like a function call:

```
r = client.service.getVesselSummaryXMLString('str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5', 'str6', 'str7', 'str8')
```

If you want to send the dictionary, then you need to prepare the dict as follows:

```
request_data = {'VesselID': 'str1', 'VesselName': 'string', 'CallSign': 'string', 'VIN': 'string', 'HIN': 'string', 'Flag': 'string', 'Service': 'string', 'BuildYear': 'str8'}
 r = client.service.getVesselSummaryXMLString(**request_data )
```

hope this answers the question.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you!

Comment: Maybe @jeleffto accepted this answer but the question title clearly says that the request.xml data has to be parsed into python dict and then it should be passed to zeep client